# Popup LOV not showing selection when changed

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a popup LOV page item in my oracle APEX application who's list is pulled with a SQL query.  When I try to change the value of the popup LOV from runtime the new value is not displayed in the page item.

I can tell that the change is registering and that the value is being stored because I have a dynamic action that depends on the value of the page item that is working correctly.  In addition to that the debugger is confirming that the value is being stored in the page item but the page item isn't displaying a value.

A few other things that might be worth noting:

- When I statically assign a value to the page item that value displays as intended but when I switch the value from the static assignment it doesn't show up.
- I have other popup LOV page items that are doing almost the exact same thing in the same application and don't seem to have this problem.  I have double checked the attributes of the page items and I can't find any discrepancies that would cause this, but I am new to Oracle APEX so I might have missed something.

Comment: If you did everything the same as with other similar items but this one isn't working properly, *maybe* something happened in Apex' metadata (read: bug). Try to delete this item and start over, possibly giving that newly created item a different name.

Comment: I did that and had the same issue

Answer (score 0):

After removing the popup LOV page item as one of the "items to submit" in a dynamic action that was triggered on the popup LOV changing, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Got same issue.
Find out the reason is wrong database column data type. CHAR type in my case, but APEX select-list working only at VARCHAR2. After changing table column data type have to set select-list position once again.